# ViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated immediately after presentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried to hide a ViewController using "dismissViewControllerAnimated" immediately after "presentViewController"

```
AddTaskViewController *add = [[AddTaskViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:add animated:NO completion:nil];
[add dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but I have a delay before the ViewController is hidded ?

Thanks

Comment: HAve you tried : [add dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; ?

Comment: Have you tried not presenting the view controller in the first place? What is the point of presenting and then immediately dismissing it?